# Do I need a visa to go to Canada from America if I am Vietnamese have tourist visa of USA?

Tags: visas, usa, canada

I want to go to Toronto to visit my brother only for 5 days and will come back to the USA. I also want to see the water fall through the border between Canada and USA. I am now staying in Milwaukee, Chicago and I'm Vietnamese, I have a one year, multi-tourist USA visa. Do I need a Canadian visa?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do need a visa.

Your USA visa has nothing to do with allowance to cross the Canadian border.

The only way it might be beneficial is when you will apply for Canadian visa at their embassy, it'll be easier to get the visa since you already have the US one.